# Is it possible to display pdf on a single view without using webview?

Tags: ios, pdf

I'm trying to display pdf using `CGPDFDocumentRef`. I got stuck in the middle as I don't know what has to be done after that to display on my view:

MyViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TestPage" withExtension:@"pdf"];

    CGPDFDocumentRef PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    CGPDFPageRef PDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFDocument, 1);
}
```

The PDF page has to be added to the context. I referred to some code but I don't understand how to add the pdf page to the context and display it on the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a `UIView` subclass and override the `drawRect`

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, currentPage);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, [self bounds].size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, [self bounds], 0, true));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page);    
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

Where `document` and `currentPage` are

```
CGPDFDocumentRef document;
int currentPage;
```

which could be initialised in `initWithFrame`

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        NSString *pathToPdfDoc = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aa" ofType:@"pdf"];
        NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToPdfDoc];
        document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
        currentPage = 1;
        totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document);

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: where to add UIview? ViewController already has a view right and then why we have to add? Where we have to override rect method??

Comment: You need a custom `UIView` sub class. `drawRect` is a method of UIView class that you have to override

Comment: It's working,thanks.But how to render pdf with multiple pages?

Comment: You can increase/decrease the `currentPage` through some logic and call [self setNeedsDisplay]. But the recommended way is to add each pages(PDF Views with different `currentPage` value) to a scrollView

Answer (score 1):

Look at using [`QLPreviewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead for a simple way of displaying a PDF without a web view. This view controller also makes sharing / printing the PDF simple.

Comment: i came to know that QLPreviewController is not supported in ios 7.

Comment: Really, hadn't heard that (and it would cause a lot of problems). Where did you learn that?

Comment: i just browsed and got to know that PDF can't be displayed using QLPreviewController in iOS 7 but i didn't try it by myself

Comment: I don't have a link,i didn't take a note on that.I jus googled QLPreviewController in iOS 7,some people have posted it's not working.

Comment: Not very good research... Not working for them doesn't mean not working. Search for `QLPreviewController in iOS 6` and you'll see even more people with problems - but it certainly does work.

Comment: Okay fine..Let me see to it.Thanks

Comment: nice! is it faster that using a UIWebView?